# loading scripts inside an async function causes problems

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

```
const loading = document.getElementById('loading_screen')
const page = document.getElementById('main')

function hide_page() {
  console.log('1')
  loading.style.display = 'block'
  loading.style.opacity = '1'
  loading.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    page.style.display = 'none'
  })

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    loading.ontransitionend = resolve
  })
}

function display_page() {
  console.log('2')
  page.style.display = 'flex'
  loading.style.opacity = '0'
  loading.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    loading.style.display = 'none'
  })

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    loading.ontransitionend = resolve
  })
}

function load_scripts(files) {
  var promises = []
  files.forEach((src) => {
    let script = document.createElement("script")
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
    script.setAttribute('class', 'local_script')
    script.async = false;
    script.setAttribute('src', src)
    document.getElementById('head').appendChild(script)
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
      script.onload = resolve
      script.onerror = resolve
    }));
  })
  return Promise.all(promises)
}

async function f1() {
  await hide_page()
  await load_scripts(some_scripts_urls);
  // load_scripts(some_scripts_urls); //this works, it's displayed 2 at the console, but the scripts are executed after and I don't want that
  await display_page();
  console.log('3')
}
f1()
```

The `display_page(`) function is executed, i.e. 2 appears at the console only when I don't put `await` to the `load_scripts()` function. The `load_scripts()` function makes sure that a list of scripts are loaded and executed before displaying the page, so that everything is functional when the page appears. If I remove `await` from `load_scripts()`, the page will already display before the scripts are loaded and executed.

Comment: What exactly is the question/problem?

Comment: @EssXTee why the display_page() function is not executed?

Comment: You're loading the scripts synchronously. There's no need to use promises to wait for them to load.

Comment: @Barmar Scripts that are added to the DOM are always loaded asynchronously, regardless whether `script.async = false` or not

Comment: @Giovanni5454 Do all the `promises` that `Promise.all` waits for actually fulfill? Try to add some logging to the `onload`/`onerror` handlers - do the events actually fire? Also check your devtools: are you getting any errors? Do the scripts load an execute as expected?